# Find the interior of the set $\{ 1, 1/2, 1/3,\ldots\}$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If we assume that this set is subset of $\mathbb{R}$ then the interior set is the empty set.

Comment: That depends. As a subset of itself, its interior is the set itself.

Comment: What do you mean 'If we don't consider the set subset of R"? There is no notion of the interior of a topological space unless you just mean the interior of the space within itself in which case it's the entire space (because it is open).

Comment: I don't understand why N is an open set. IF we want to write it as an interval it would be [1,infinity) right? so how come it's open? can you please explain?

Comment: I assume you are defining $N$ to be the set $\{\frac{1}{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}^+\}$ with the subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}$. If that's true, then $N$ is a topological space and by definition of a topology, $N$ is open in $N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define the interior as: 
$$\text{int }S :=\{s\in S\ |\ \ \forall \ \varepsilon >0, S\cap B(s,\varepsilon)\backslash\{s\}\neq \emptyset\}$$

...then the interior is empty. In other words, any element of your set is going to have a ball around it which when we look at, has nothing in $S$ other than the point you started with.

For some arbitrary point $s=\frac{1}{n}$ in $S$, think about balls around $s$ of size less than $\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$.

(In my notation, $B(s,\varepsilon)$ deonotes the open $\varepsilon$-ball around $s$)